# Assembly Language error in masm

Tags: assembly, masm

```
TITLE PGM16_3A:  BEEP
EXTRN TIMER_FLAG:BYTE

PUBLIC BEEP

.MODEL SMALL
.CODE
BEEP PROC

PUSH CX

MOV BL,0B6H
OUT 43H,AL

MOV AX,1193
OUT 42H,AL
MOV AL,AH
OUT 42H,AL
;ACTIVATE SPEAKER

IN AL,61H
MOV AH,AL
OR AL,11B
OUT 61H,AL

MOV CX,9
B_1:CMP TIMER_FLAG,1
JNE B_1
MOV TIMER_FLAG,0
LOOP B_1

MOV AL,AH ;      
END BEEP
```

There is an error "unmatched block nesting: BEEP" on line 36,

I am beginner so there may be some silly mistake... 
Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You need `BEEP ENDP` before `END BEEP`. `ENDP` closes the procedure that you have begun with `PROC` and `END` ends the module giving an optional entry point. Read the manual for further information.